# Proving that any polynomial in a field $K$ can be "expanded" about any point in $K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, solution-verification

This post concerns the subsection "Division of Polynomials", pages 76--77, in the textbook *Analysis I* by Amann and Escher. I would appreciate feedback on my attempted proof of Proposition 8.16.

**Excerpt from text:**

> [image]

**Further context:**

> [image]

**My attempt:**

We proceed by induction on $n \in \mathbb N$, the degree of the polynomial $p \in K[X]$.

*Base case:* Assume $\deg (p) = 0$. That means $p$ is a constant polynomial $p = b_0$, so there is certainly a unique $b_0$ such that $p = \sum_{k = 0}^0 (X - a)^k b_k = b_0$.

*Induction step:* Assume the result is true for all polynomials of degree $n$. Consider $p \in K[X]$ such that $\deg (p) = n + 1$. Because $\deg (X - a) = 1$, we can use Proposition 8.15 and divide $p$ by $X - a$. There are therefore unique polynomials $p_{(1)}$ and $b_0'$ such that $p = (X - a)p_{(1)} + b_0'$.

We see that $\deg(b_0') = 0$, and because we are in a field, we must have $\deg \big( (X - a)p_{(1)} \big) = \deg (X - a) + \deg (p_{(1)})$, which implies that $\deg(p_{(1)}) = n + 1 - 1 = n$. Therefore, by the inductive assumption $p_{(1)}$ has unique $b_0, b_1, \dots, b_n \in K$ such that $p_{(1)} = \sum_{k = 0}^n b_k (X - a)^k$.

Thus, $p = \sum_{k = 0}^n b_k(X - a)^{k + 1} + b_0'$, and simply relabeling the $b$ terms will give the desired result.

**Questions:**

Is my attempt correct?

I am a little confused about how $b_0'$ is considered a polynomial in $K[X]$ but also simply an element in $K$. (The same thing seems to happen in the text's outline of a proof of Proposition 8.16.) The text says on page 73 that a ring $R$ is isomorphic with its constant power series ring $RX^0$. Presumably this is true for a field $K$ as well. Is that an issue I'm glossing over in my proof?

I appreciate any help.

**Edit:**

User Gone says that I didn't prove uniqueness. I somehow thought that uniqueness in Proposition 8.15 would guarantee uniqueness in Proposition 8.16. Assuming I am wrong, I will go ahead and try to prove uniqueness here.

Assume there were $b_0, b_1, \dots, b_n \in K$ and $b_0', b_1', \dots, b_n' \in K$ such that $p = \sum_{k = 0}^n b_k (X - a)^k = \sum_{k = 0}^n b_k' (X - a)^k$.  Subtracting one expansion from the other and using basic field properties, we have $0 = \sum_{k = 0}^n (b_k - b_k')(X - a)^k$. The only way the polynomial on the right could be equal to $0$ is if $b_k - b_k' = 0$ for $k = 0, 1, \dots, n$. This proves uniqueness.

This proof of uniqueness doesn't use Proposition 8.15 at all, so I'm not sure it's right.

**Edit 2:**

Forget about the prior attempt to prove uniqueness. Assume there were $b_0, b_1, \dots, b_n \in K$ and $b_0', b_1', \dots, b_n' \in K$ such that $p = \sum_{k = 0}^n b_k (X - a)^k = \sum_{k = 0}^n b_k' (X - a)^k$. We can effectively divide $p$ by $X - a$ by writing the following:

\begin{align*}
p = \sum_{k = 0}^n b_k (X - a)^k &= (X - a)\sum_{k = 1}^n b_k (X - a)^{k - 1} + b_0 \\
p = \sum_{k = 0}^n b_k' (X - a)^k &= (X - a)\sum_{k = 1}^n b_k' (X - a)^{k - 1} + b_0'.
\end{align*}

Proposition 8.15 tells us that $\sum_{k = 1}^n b_k (X - a)^{k - 1} = \sum_{k = 1}^n b_k' (X - a)^{k - 1}$ and $b_0 = b_0'$. If we call the sums $p_{(1)}$, then $\deg(p_{(1)}) = n - 1$. We can repeat this procedure, dividing $p_{(1)}$ by $X - a$ and showing that $b_1 = b_1'$, and so on until polynomial

\begin{align*}
p_{(n)} = \sum_{k = n}^n b_k (X - a)^{n - n} = \sum_{k = n}^n b_k' (X - a)^{n - n}
\end{align*}

has degree $0$, at which point division is no longer required and we see from the degenerate summation that $b_n = b_n'$. This completes the proof that $b_0 = b_0', b_1 = b_1', \dots, b_n = b_n'$ and therefore the coefficients of the expansion around $a$ are unique.

Comment: You did not prove *uniqueness*.

Comment: @Gone Uniqueness is not guaranteed by Proposition 8.15? Maybe I am confused.

Comment: You need to *prove* how it yields uniqueness in Prop 8.16,  The "proof" in the book is only a sketch (or a hint). I presume you wish to flesh it out to a complete proof so all is clear.

Comment: @Gone I gave it a shot. Not too confident that it's correct.

Comment: "The only way" is something that requires proof. What happened to your idea to use P.8.15?

Comment: @Gone I rewrote the proof of uniqueness. I think it's better. Thanks for sticking with me.

Comment: I've gone ahead and fleshed out my extended comments into an answer as it was getting lengthy. Thanks again for this very nice answer!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to both you and Bill Dubuque for this very nice solution.

Just two small notes for me (as I now arrive here while reading Amann Escher):

(1) In the induction step saying "We see that $\deg(b_0') = 0$..." is not strictly speaking correct, since all we have is that $\deg(b_0') < 1$ (the zero polynomial for example does not obey your claim), but this is immaterial as either way we obtain a constant power series (isomorphic to $b_0 \in K$ per the bottom of p.72) as you have done.

(2) There is (at least to my taste) the tiniest bit extra that needs to be shown at the end of your existence argument. In particular, once we have arrived at the decomposition $p = (X - a)p_{(1)} + b_0'$ we have, from equations (8.19) and (8.20) (and that $K$ a field so there's no subadditivity of degrees when multiplying) that $n+1 \deg p = \max \{ \deg (X-a) + \deg p_{(1)}, 0\} = \max \{ 1 + \deg p_{(1)}, 0\}$. Now from here we need to show that $p_{(1)} \neq 0$ so that $\deg p_{(1)} \neq - \infty$ so that the maximum in the above comes out to $1 + \deg p_{(1)}$ and then we can proceed as you do. That $p_{(1)} \neq 0$ follows because, if it were, then $p = b_0'$ and so has degree $\leq 0$, contradicting that $\deg p = n+1$ for $n = 0,1,2...$.